# How to enable HTML speech apis in Chromium

Tags: raspbian, chromium, speech-recognition

It looks like in the Raspberry Pi builds, the JavaScript speech apis do not work. However, no errors appear.

They work on Chromium on my laptop, but not on my RPi.

Tested on:

- Ubuntu Mate, Chromium 48
- Raspbian, Chromium 51

What is the solution? I like the accuracy of Google text to speech and I'd like to use it in a JavaScript program.

How to fix this?